# Date into timestamps conversion

Tags: php, date, datetime, timestamp

I am using xampp server and i have set timezone to my current timezone.I am trying to insert date and time into my database but the are some problems with in getting date function.

## Dates

**My current time: 26-07-2014 10:15:03 AM.**

1. When I get date from php `date('d-m-Y , h:m:s');` it is showing me the right time just difference 6 minute.

   **The result of `date('d-m-Y , h:m:s');` :**  27-07-2014 , 10:07:32
2. When I get date from `date("d-m-Y g:i:s A")` it is showing me exact time.

   **The result of `date("d-m-Y g:i:s A");` :**  27-07-2014 10:14:32 AM

---

## Timestamps

1. When I get timestamp from php `echo strtotime("now");` it is behind five hours from standtime.

   **The result of `echo strtotime("now");` :** 1406438072;

   **Ater conversion:** Sun, 27 Jul 2014 05:14:32 GMT
2. When I converted  `date('d-m-Y , h:m:s');` into timestamp it is behind 5 hours from standtime.

   **The result of converted  `date('d-m-Y , h:m:s');` :** 1406437652

   **After conversion:** Sun, 27 Jul 2014 05:07:32 GMT
3. When I converted `date("d-m-Y g:i:s A");` into timestamp its is behind five hours again.

   **The result of converted  `date("d-m-Y g:i:s A");` :** 1406438072

   **After conversion:** Sun, 27 Jul 2014 05:14:32 GMT

And my current timezone is `Asia/Karachi`.

> **problem:**
>   Can anyone tell me why i get behind 5 hours from my timezone when i convert my date into timestamp and what is the proper solution to convert date into timestamp?

Comment: try this `echo strtotime(date('d-M-Y g:i:s A'));`

Comment: can you post some code where you have set the zone.

Comment: Can you please post the exact code and output? While I'm not implying your interpretation is wrong, it's easy to get wrong results inadvertently due to typos.

Comment: you need to check php.ini for timezone value .. then in database also check `select now()` see what output it gives you the update time zone there

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario okay i will update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format/diagnose PHP code is not correct. You have this all around it:

```
d-m-Y , h:m:s
  ^       ^
```

It's also just not possible that this same code:

```
date('d-m-Y , h:m:s')
```

... prints theses entirely different results:

```
6-07-2014 , 05:07:47
1406333267
```

So I guess there're possibly this and some other typos in your real code. Computers are really picky about that :)

Answer (score 1):

you should change your format try this

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); // for india 
// you  can set your timezone in above line
// date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi'); // for pakistan
$date = date('d-m-Y g:i:s A')."\n"; 
echo $date;
$time = strtotime($date);
echo "\n".$time."\n";
echo "\n".date('d-m-Y g:i:s A', $time);
?>
```

**OUPUT :**

```
26-07-2014 11:59:23 AM

1406375963

26-07-2014 11:59:23 AM
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/172080)

Comment: It is giving date and time right but when i convert it to timestamp then i get behind 5 hours.

Comment: @TheRealHamza set your timezone correctly. post what is your timezone(country)

Comment: my time zone is set correctly. thats why i getting right time.

Comment: try this above code in a fresh file with your timezone. you will get the correct output.

Answer (score 1):

It's the matter of timezone. Try using [`localtime()`](http://php.net//manual/en/function.localtime.php) function.
Or maybe use something like function [`date_timezone_set()`](http://php.net//manual/en/function.date-timezone-set.php).

Answer (score 1):

I have a problem on my rented server where the time is off by two hours from what I have locally.

So what I do to get the correct time is this:

`$new_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+2 hours'));`

Then I just use `$new_time` where I need it.

Works like a charm.

Comment: Let me guess you live in +2 timezone?

Comment: ... where the timezone offset does not change twice a year ;-)